# TextView not filling width? (android)

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this `TextView` defined in the XML layout file:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

This `TextView` should be from end to end of the display, as `layout_width="fill_parent"`. But this is not the case when I run it on the emulator. This is how it looks:
[image]

Why is it( the time) not covering the entire width of the screen?

Comment: The width is just the size of the container. Increase the font size to make it larger. It won't auto scale

Comment: @Kirk If I use a larger font, won't it look very large on devices with smaller screen? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Use device independent sizes like dip. They look the same on all screen sizes in general. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Kirk Increasing font size still won't let it reach the ends of the screen, as the screen's width is greater than its height.

Answer (score 0):

> `Textview` is the component not a layout , component are set in layout 
>   . so most of time components height and width are depends on there
>   parent layout

that property set the text view contain in center , if you want to check the area of the text view just simply set some background color .

Answer (score 0):

This simple open source, can be very helpful `AutoScale TextView`: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/autoscale-textview/
or look into the implementation and adjust it to your app.